# Grafana duplicates legends with increase function

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a prometheus query like **increase(success_count_total[24h])**. It is working fine except that It starts duplicating the legends(see attached image). Kindly suggest if we can combine the legends and stop the repeation. I tried **count(prometheus_query) by (message_type)** but it was not giving the expected result.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Grafana's legend adds entry for each time series received from the expression.  From the screenshot it seems like expression `increase(success_count_total[24h])` returns 3 time series with unique labels. But in the legend you substitute those labels with just `Success` name. If you remove the `Success` word from your panel's legend settings - Grafana will plot all the labels as is.
If you want to get exactly one line for your query - wrap it wit aggregation function:

```
sum(increase(success_count_total[24h]))
```

This would produce exactly one result and panel's legend will show only one line per expression.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am getting data from different different pods  and for same matric but for different pods  i am seeing a new legend. Can we combine the legends by pod name?

Comment: Sure! You can do this by updating the expression to `sum(increase(success_count_total[24h])) by(pod)` (I assume pod name is under label `pod`) and changing the Legend field to `{{pod}}`.

Comment: With the increase(success_count_total[24h]), I am getting correct results but putting this in sum() function giving me incorrect results. Can we combine the legends by metric_type and with increase function?

Answer (score 0):

there is a workaround:

1. in options, change type to instant, and apply
2. in options, change type back to range, and apply
   the legends is not duplicate now :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).